# Different rendering when using Drawable and Image Resource? ImageButton - Android

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have something strange in here. I have the very same image being loaded in two different ways:

Here is the code:

```
     if(imageAddress.startsWith("drawable")){
         btn.setImageResource(this.getResources().getIdentifier(imageAddress, null, this.getPackageName()));
     }else{
         btn.setImageURI(Uri.parse(new File(imageAddress).toString()));
     }
```

As you can see above, I test if the image address begins with "drawable", if it does, then I load the image as a drawable. If it doesn't, then it's an image from sdcard, then I load it through its URI.

Here is the code for the ImageButton:

```
    <ImageButton  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorners" 
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".95">
    </ImageButton>
```

And below is the RESULT of this:

[image: Image when loaded AS DRAWABLE]
Above image shows ImageButton when loaded AS DRAWABLE (imageAddress = "drawable/eu_quero")

[image: Image when loaded through IMAGEURI]
Above image shows ImageButton when loaded THROUGH IMAGE URI (imageAddress = "/mnt/sdcard/myapp/images/eu_quero.png")

**What I need is the images to be the same size, no matter if I load it as drawable or through ImageURI.**

Can anyone help me please??

**IMPORTANT: IMAGES ARE EXACTLY THE SAME!!! SAME SIZE!!**

Comment: Interesting problem, you can try loading the sd-card image as a drawable: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#createFromPath%28java.lang.String%29
and then add to your imagebutton with `btn.setImageDrawable()` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try implementing  android:margin_left  instead of padding:left ?