# Different dimensions when using image from drawable and loading from sdcard

Tags: android, imageview

I have an application in which i am setting the background of an image view.
If i keep my images in the re/drawable(s) folder, everything works fine but if i keep the same images in the sdcard and load from there to set the background then the dimensions of the image are different.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064808/different-rendering-when-using-drawable-and-image-resource-imagebutton-androi) had been asked earlier but it is still unanswered. Could anyone shed some light on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

if we place the images in res/drawable(s) folder then android chooses the appropriate image according to target device and scaling is also done by system if required. So if you are putting a image in sdcard then system does not do any scaling on image.

Comment: So is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: simply it is not possibble. But for achieving this you to implement your own logic.